# Is it possible to have custom reverse geocoding?

Tags: ios, swift, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Currently, I'm utilizing reverse geocoding to simply convert a longitude and latitude to a locality and sub locality.

Is it possible for me to override this and essentially have it return custom strings at my discretion given that I provide it with the coordinates? Any thoughts?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {


    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    if(locations.count > 0){


        let location = locations[0] as! CLLocation

        //            println(location.coordinate)


        if let currentLocatino = currLocation {
            if CLLocation(latitude: currentLocatino.latitude, longitude: currentLocatino.longitude).distanceFromLocation(location) > 500 {
                currLocation = location.coordinate
                self.skip = 0
                self.loadObjects()

            }
        }
        else {
            currLocation = location.coordinate
            self.skip = 0
            self.loadObjects()
        }


        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: currLocation!.latitude, longitude: currLocation!.longitude), completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in


            if error != nil {
                println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {
                let date = NSDate()
                let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
                formatter.stringFromDate(date)
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark


                var testifempty = "\(pm.subLocality)"
                if testifempty == "nil"
                {
                    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                    if let lbutton = self.lbutton{
                        lbutton.text = "Hello  " + "\(pm.locality)" //+ "\n" + formatter.stringFromDate(date)


                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                    if let lbutton = self.lbutton {
                        lbutton.text = "Hello  " + "\(pm.subLocality)\n" // + formatter.stringFromDate(date)
                    }

                }
            }

            else {
                println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })

    } else {


        println("Cannot fetch your location")

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using `CoreLocation`, Google Map API or something else? Could you show me a little more details of what you are working on and what you would like it to be? Providing code would be the best.

Comment: @Ducky added in my code calling reverse geocoding. Simply-ish put, I'd like to be able to input coordinates manually and override the reverse geocoding with my own string.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the names are, you might try a switch that swapped out matching strings.

```
var locale_string

switch locale_string {
case “name1”:
let displayed_locale_name = “changed_name1”
case “name2”:
let displayed_locale_name = “changed_name2”

...
}
```

Then, the default case where you haven't identified the locale could accept the string as it is.
I got the idea from the Swift2 Programming Language Guide, page 17.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse geocoding is basically a spatial query. I would suggest to define a map with spatial boundaries, assign each boundary an attribute for both locality and sub-locality.

With that map, you can run your set of coordinates against it and assign them the same attributes as the coordinate fits in one of the spatial boundaries.

Comment: Can you go a bit more in depth?